# JUnit testing public boolean equals(Object obj)

Tags: java, junit

I am working on JUnit testing a project I'm working on, and ran into a wall testing the following method:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (!(obj instanceof Vehicle)) {
     return false;
  }
  else {
     Vehicle other = (Vehicle) obj;
     return (owner + yearMakeModel + value).
        equals(other.owner + other.yearMakeModel
        + other.value);
```

I am using the following tests to test instnaceof, however, it does not seem to be testing the correct code.  After submitting, This section of my code is highlighted and I am seeing a message that this method is not executed in my testing.

```
/** 
 * instanceof test false.
 */ 
 @Test public void instanceOfFalseTest() {
      Car car1 = new Car("Jones, Sam", "2017 Honda Accord", 222000, true);
      Object obj = new Object();
      Assert.assertFalse(obj instanceof Vehicle);
   } 
/** 
 * instanceof test true.
 */ 
@Test public void instanceOfTrueTest() {
      Car car1 = new Car("Jones, Sam", "2017 Honda Accord", 222000, true);
      Object obj = new Object();
      Assert.assertTrue(car1 instanceof(Vehicle);
```

Comment: what's wrong with this? you mean your `equals()` method is not called ?

Comment: In JUnit, one shouldn't test java libraries or external libraries, one should test his code. You should test equals function, not instanceof keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer by Nikolas nicely explains why your current tests are pointless. A more reasonable test could look like this:

```
Car car1 = new Car("Jones, Sam", "2017 Honda Accord", 222000, true);
Car car2 = new Car("Jones, Sam", "2017 Honda Accord", 222000, true);
Car car3 = new Car("Jones, Samual", "2017 Honda Accord", 222000, true);

assertThat(car1, is(car2));
assertThat(car1, not(car3));
```

where `is()` refers to a [Java Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/) matcher (they allow you to write down your test cases in very elegant ways).

You want to think up all the possible ways how two objects could be equal, nor *not* equal. And then, you (at least) one test case for each of those cases. Ideally, they each go into a separate, independent @Test method.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to test Java's `instanceof` operator,
because it is a built-in functionality of the JVM, not developed by you.

You should rather test your `equals` method.
For example like this:

```
@Test public void equalsFalseTest1() {
    Car car1 = new Car("Jones, Sam", "2017 Honda Accord", 222000, true);
    Object obj = new Object();
    Assert.assertNotEquals(car1, obj);
}

@Test public void equalsFalseTest2() {
    Car car1 = new Car("Jones, Sam", "2017 Honda Accord", 222000, true);
    Car car2 = new Car("Doe, John", "2017 Honda Accord", 222000, true);
    Assert.assertNotEquals(car1, car2);
}

@Test public void equalsTrueTest() {
    Car car1 = new Car("Jones, Sam", "2017 Honda Accord", 222000, true);
    Car car2 = new Car("Jones, Sam", "2017 Honda Accord", 222000, true);
    Assert.assertEquals(car1, car2);
}
```

Then your `equals` method is actually called.

Comment: You wrote your answer while I was writing mine offline, but well, our answers are bit different, so I guess I will keep mine around, too ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat similar answers, but not equal ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The Java's `instanceof` is part of the JVM instruction set, it's a specific same-named instruction. If interested, read the Chapter 6. The Java Virtual Machine Instruction Set: [6.5. Instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.instanceof).

Luckily, there is neither a way to `@Override` the implementation nor change the behavior - this implies this feature is untestable and there is no need to test if an object is an instance of another since the definition using `extends` and `implements` key-words.

Note that the method [`Object::equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) is irrelevant to do with this operator/instruction.

Comment: I like your links here, and I like that you left some "space" for other answers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The other answer:

```
 @Test public void instanceOfFalseTest() {
  Object obj = new Object();
  assertThat(obj, instanceOf(Vehicle.class));
} 

 @Test public void instanceOfTrueTest() {
  Car car1 = new Car("Jones, Sam", "2017 Honda Accord", 222000, true);
  Object obj = new Object();
  assertThat(car1, instanceOf(Vehicle.class));
}
```

, where instanceOf() check if an Object is an instance of a given class.

Click reference hamcrest [instanceOf()](https://code.google.com/archive/p/hamcrest/wikis/Tutorial.wiki)